# Spotify/iPod like now playing view

Tags: iphone, ios

I am developing a radio app which streams mp3 from the internet. I have a custom view to control the playback(play/stop).

I would like to implement Spotify like "Now Playing" view with volume controller view at the buttom. I know MPMoviePlayerViewController can be used, but this view is not like Spotify/iPod.

Anybody know how to solve this problem? Can i reuse a view from the Apple API?

[image: Screenshot of the view]

Comment: A screenshot / mockup would help understanding what you really plan to achieve.

Comment: Hi! Now I uploaded a screenshot...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll need to make this view yourself, but what else is new.

As for the volume view, easiest to use is this, and it works well with AirPlay:

http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/mediaplayer/reference/MPVolumeView_Class/Reference/Reference.html